# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project sakai-kernel-impl: There are test failures

Tags: java, maven, installation, sakai

Sakai 10 install error:

error text:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project sakai-kernel-impl: There are test failures.
```

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Means simply some test cases have failed so what is the real problem?

Comment: If we're talking about [this](https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai) Sakai, then I just checked-out the project and it compiled successfully. Are you using Java 8 with Maven 3.2 (at least)?

Comment: Lots of Sakai tests fail when you `mvn install` it. It's a good idea to have a look at the error messages, but I've learnt to just skip them by adding ` -Dmaven.test.skip=true`.

Comment: You'd need to add more details about what failed. In Sakai 11 the tests are frequently run and have been passing. Tests that don't pass have been fixed. There may be some intermittent failures that haven't been back-ported or still exist since 10 isn't as often compiled.